# React Native - .ENVs are undefined in Metro Bundler's config file when bundling iOS apps

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native, environment-variables, metro-bundler

I have NPM scripts that build and run our app with mocked backend data (used for component testing). They set ENVs inline using the cross-env npm package.

`"android-mock": "cross-env MOCK_BACKEND=1 NODE_ENV=development node generate-config.js && react-native run-android -- --reset-cache",` - emulator runs on Windows

`"ios-mock": "cross-env MOCK_BACKEND=1 NODE_ENV=development node generate-config.js && react-native run-ios -- --reset-cache",` - simulator runs on MacOS

---

Metro bundler looks for the `MOCK_BACKEND` env and based on that, it resolves paths so that the app uses mocked data instead of relying on the backend to get it.

**Problem**: Metro can read the `process.env.MOCK_BACKEND` value only when bundling Android apps, on iOS, the value returns undefined.

---

What is the correct way to define ENVs so that Metro can read them properly also for iOS bundling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know why, but it seems like Metro overwrites set ENVs when bundling iOS apps.
Elsewhere ENVs are defined.

If anyone comes over this problem, this is how I solved it.

#### Solution

**1**. In the `generate-config.js` script that is in NPM scrips above, I have added NODE_ENV checks. The script generates the `config.js` inside the public folder, based on NODE_ENV.

```
const fs = require("fs");
console.log( process.env.NODE_ENV);

if(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'){
  fs.copyFile("config.runtime.js","public/config.js",(err) => {if(!err){console.log(err)}});
} else if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'mock'){
  fs.copyFile("config.mock.js","public/config.js",(err) => {if(!err){console.log(err)}});
} else {
  fs.copyFile("config.debug.js","public/config.js",(err) =>{if(!err){console.log(err)}});
}
```

**2**. I have imported generated `config.js` into Metro.config and used it as needed.

`const config = require(path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/config.js'));`

config.js for reference:

```
module.exports = {
    isProduction : false,
    disableCache: true,
    API:"http://alanj.bs.local:15455/",
    /////////////////////////////////////
    // ENVs
    /////////////////////////////////////
    MOCKED_BACKEND: 1,
    /////////////////////////////////////
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We ran into the same issue, we have no solution yet but interesting observations after approximately 1 day of trial and error:

### Start Packager Script

The 'Start Packager' script in Xcode is responsible for the mess.
It does not pass the environment variables to the packager.

### The problem lies within Mac OS `open`:

Create a new file `/tmp/test.command`:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
echo "Environment Variable XXX='$XXX'"
```

Now use

```
XXX="visible" /tmp/test.command
```

This will print

```
Environment Variable XXX='visible'
```

Whereas when called with `open`:

```bash
XXX="not visible" open /tmp/test.command
```

will just yield:

```
Environment Variable XXX=''
```

Even with

```bash
XXX="not visible" open --env XXX="abc" /tmp/test.command
```

we just get:

```
Environment Variable XXX=''
```

Not sure if we should file a support ticket at Apple